# Create std::thread from native handle?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a `std::thread` object `t`, I can use `t.native_handle()` to get access to the API of the underlying thread implementation (e.g., pthreads or Windows threads).  But what if I have a handle from the underlying thread implementation (e.g., a pthreads thread).  Is there any way to transform that into a C++11 `std::thread`?

The motivation for this is that it might be desirable to use the native platform threading API to set up a thread with, e.g., a particular affinity or a particular stack size (or some other characteristic that is not accessible via the C++11 API).  From that point forward, however, it'd be nice to stick to the C++11 functionality.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GCC you can construct a `std::thread::id` from a `std::thread::native_handle_type` but you cannot construct a `std::thread` from it.

This means you can test whether a given `pthread_t` refers to the same thread as a `std::thread` object (or to `this_thread::get_id()`) but you cannot create new `thread` objects from it.

A `std::thread` is designed to be a *unique* handle to a thread. The only way for a different `thread` object to take ownership of the underlying thread is by moving it from the original, so only one object "owns" it at once.  If you could construct them from a native handle you could do:

```
// start new thread
std::thread t(&thread_func);

// now have two handles to the same thread
std::thread t2( t.native_handle() );

std::thread t1.join();

// erm, hang on, this isn't right
std::thread t2.join();
```

> The motivation for this is that it might be desirable to use the native platform threading API to set up a thread with, e.g., a particular affinity or a particular stack size (or some other characteristic that is not accessible via the C++11 API).

Ideally the platform would allow you to specify parameters such as affinity or stacksize when you construct the thread, which would allow you to use those platform-specific features without weakening the type system by constructing "non-owning" `thread` objects... but at least GCC doesn't support doing that.